# Dexie's Version.upgrade() using typescript

Tags: typescript, dexie

I am having a typescript application using Dexie. I would like to create a new version where I also want to populate the the table using Version.upgrade().

I extended the sample https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/tree/master/samples/typescript as following:

```
export interface ICity {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
}

export class AppDatabase extends Dexie {

    contacts: Dexie.Table<Contact, number>;
    emails: Dexie.Table<IEmailAddress, number>;
    phones: Dexie.Table<IPhoneNumber, number>;
    cities: Dexie.Table<ICity, number>;

    constructor() {

        super("ContactsDatabase");

        var db = this;

        //
        // Define tables and indexes
        //
        db.version(1).stores({
            contacts: '++id, firstName, lastName',
            emails: '++id, contactId, type, email',
            phones: '++id, contactId, type, phone',
        });

        db.version(2).stores({
            cities: '++id, name'
        }).upgrade((tx: Dexie.Transaction) => {
            tx.table("cities").bulkAdd([
                { name: "London" },
                { name: "Berlin" },
                { name: "Paris" }
            ]);
        });

        // Let's physically map Contact class to contacts table.
        // This will make it possible to call loadEmailsAndPhones()
        // directly on retrieved database objects.
        db.contacts.mapToClass(Contact);
    }
}
```

But it did not work as intended.

Has someone a hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade function will only run for clients having version 1 installed. A clean browser will go directly to version 2 without upgrade function.

Solution : add a populate function that inits the cities table.

```
    db.on('populate', () => db.cities.bulkAdd([
      { name: "London" },
      { name: "Berlin" },
      { name: "Paris" }
    ]));
```

Keep your upgrade function as well if your users may be on version 1 still.

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand the documentation correctly (http://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Design#the-populate-event) then this event will only be triggered when the database is created. I am also looking for the opportunity to populate a table initially when added later through a scheme migration.

Comment: You will need to use both populate and upgrade. The API distinguishes between upgrades and populate as upgrades are expected to perform diffs in data and should never change. whilst populate can change according to what is needed in latest version. If for example, you add another city Stockholm, your users on version 2 will only need one city added while brand new users will need all four. So all four cities should be added in populate and a new version 3 with upgrade function should add Stockholm only.

Comment: I understand and it sounds right to me but when I extend the example like this - even without an upgrade function - nothing is populated:
`db.version(1).stores({
    contacts: '++id, firstName, lastName',
            emails: '++id, contactId, type, email',
            phones: '++id, contactId, type, phone',
            cities: '++id, name'
        });
        db.on('populate', () => db.cities.bulkAdd([
            { name: "London" },
            { name: "Berlin" },
            { name: "Paris" }
        ]));`

Comment: Nothing is expected to happen for already upgraded databases, neither populate or upgrade function. Have you tried deleting your database and retry running the code?

Comment: Yes, I deleted it and run the scheme migration from scratch but nothing happened. I cloned Dexie.js, added the db.on() method to the constructor of the class App database in the typescript sample. I ran the build and test commands and executed the app in the browser. I did not even got the new table cities. I  must have done something wrong.

Comment: Hard to say what could be wrong based on the info. Think I would have to look at the code (a working debuggable code with HTML and all) to find out what could be wrong.

Comment: Ok, I got it working as you have suggested: usage of upgrade and populate function. Runs either from scratch or upgrades existing version.